# Problems passing id values to Stripe API objects using cfhttp

Tags: stripe-payments, cfhttp, cfhttpparam

I am able to pass field values to Stripe's Customer object using the code

```
<cfhttp   method = "POST"  url="https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers">

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer sk_test_....."> 
    <cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="id" value = "cust_admin_18">
    <cfhttpparam type="FormField"   name="address[country]"  value = "US">
........
</cfhttp>
```

However when I try similar code with other Stripe objects, for example Payment_Method, I get an error with the id field. So

```
<cfhttp   method = "POST"  url="https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods">

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer sk_test_....."> 
    <cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="id" value = "pm_123">

    <cfhttpparam type="FormField" name="type" value = "card">

    <cfhttpparam type="FormField"   name="card[number]"  value = "4242424242424242">
.......
</cfhttp>
```

produces an error **parameter_unknown - id**

Changing "FormField" to "header" stops the error, but then the id value is not passed.

Thanks in advance for comments.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are sharing is calling the Create Payment Method [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create). You are passing card details like the card number there. You can not pass the `id` parameter, it is not a valid parameter in the API and it's what the error message tells you. So you need to remove that part since it doesn't make sense to create a PaymentMethod while passing the id of an existing one.